# radio button save selected value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this form that saves data into a database, it saves values like "necomandat" "in lucru" etc,

The form inserts a value into the database but it doesn't save the radio button checked, any idea what's wrong?

```
<input type="text" name="statuscomanda" value="<?php echo $statuscomanda; ?>" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $statuscomandatapiterii; ?>" value="$statuscomandatapiterii" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
<br>
Status Comanda Mobila: 
<br />
<input type="radio" value="" name="statuscomanda"> < - Nu a comandat mobila!
<input type="radio" value="necomandat" name="statuscomanda"> < - necomandat
<input type="radio" value="in lucru" name="statuscomanda"> < - in lucru
<input type="radio" value="finalizat (in magazin)" name="statuscomanda"> < - finalizat (in magazin) 
<input type="radio" value="expediat" name="statuscomanda"> < - expediat 
<br/><br/>
Status Comanda Tapiterii: <br />
<input type="radio" value="" name="statuscomandatapiterii"> < - Nu a comandat tapiterii!
<input type="radio" value="necomandat" name="statuscomandatapiterii"> < - necomandat
<input type="radio" value="in lucru" name="statuscomandatapiterii"> < - in lucru
<input type="radio" value="finalizat (in magazin)" name="statuscomandatapiterii">< - finalizat (in magazin)
<input type="radio" value="expediat" name="statuscomandatapiterii"> < - expediat
<br/><br/>
```

the form actually add into database nammed highmob_comenzi in table players, row "statuscomanda" a value based on the selected radio, if 2nd radio is selected, it insert into "statuscomanda" value = necomandat :) the value inserted its ok, the problem is the radio button doesnt stay checked if i refresh the page

Comment: Do you mean you want the items being still selected after form submit?

Comment: yes, and if i open the page again to see the selected radio

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read the value from the DB.

Let's say the following radio was checked:

```
<input type="radio" value="expediat" name="statuscomanda"> < - expediat
```

In that case you would simply add "checked" with your php code:

```
<input type="radio" value="expediat" name="statuscomanda" checked> < - expediat
```

Comment: it doesnt work :) this only check the radio, not reading from database :)

Comment: @PirjolNelu, Unfortunately I don't have enough information from you to give you wanted response. Knowing your code and DB structure you should be able to figure therest out

Comment: i can try to explain, the form actually add into database nammed highmob_comenzi in table players, row  "statuscomanda" a value based on the selected radio, if 2nd radio is selected, it insert into "statuscomanda" value = necomandat :) the value inserted its ok, the problem is the radio button doesnt stay checked if i refresh the page

Comment: @PirjolNelu Instead of writing here please update your question by giving full information: How do you communicate with given table? What is the structure of given table? Neverthless, my advice would be using this knowledge try to find the answer yourself. The logic is clear: if the row in your table has this radio button value checked output "checked" in your html else don't